# What are the IWWW and OWWW users for on HP UNIX?

Tags: hp-ux

What are the IWWW and OWWW users for on HP UNIX?  They are present on the machine but I don't really know what they are used for?

Answer (score 1):

These users are part of Enhanced support for Apache Webproxy. Key and certificate files should be readable (but not writable) by the user account specified by the server's configuration file "User" directive. This is often either iwww (intranet) or owww (internet).